# how modify this code to get get value and keys of map_from_arrays?

Tags: pyspark

How I can modify the following code:

```py
c1_arr = F.col('col1')
c2_arr = F.split(F.trim('col2'), '\s+')
arr_of_struct = F.transform(
    c1_arr,
    lambda x: F.struct(
        F.size(F.array_intersect(c2_arr, F.split(F.trim(x), '\s+'))).alias('cnt'),
        x.alias('val'),
    )
)
top_val = F.sort_array(arr_of_struct, False)[0]
```

`top_val` gives me an element of `col1` where it has the most common token with `col2`'s element.

Then I use the following code to get my desired result:

```
df = df.select(
    '*',
    F.when(((top_val['cnt'] > 0)),top_val['val']).alias('match'))
```

For example consider the following data:

```
col1                                                       col2
["come and get", "computer", "come and get more" ]       "come for good"
["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"]       "hot tea"
["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"]       "hot summer"
```

Desired output:

```
col1              col2                                                          match
["come and get", "computer", come and get more" ]       "come for good"         "come and get"
["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"]       "hot tea"           "hot weather"
["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"]       "hot summer"       "summer is hot"
```

Now suppose I use `map_from_arrays` function to join another column to `col1` . Then instead of `col1` I have:

```
col1_modify
{"come and get":"this is one", "computer":"useful device" ,"come and get more": "sure things"}
{"summer is hot":"about season" ,"summer is too hot":"oh yea","hot weather": "tempters"}
{"summer is hot":"about season","summer is too hot":"oh yea","hot weather":"tempters"}
```

No still I want to match with keys but I want to create a new column contains values:

output will be:

```
  match               match_value
"come and get"          "this is one"
    "hot weather"       "tempters"
 "summer is hot"         "about season"
```

in case of not using `map` function the third column can be like below, the goal is to find the right index:

```
col3
["this is one","useful device" , "sure things"]
["about season" ,"oh yea", "tempters"]
["about season","oh yea","tempters"]
```

Comment: How about keeping columns separately instead of `map_from_arrays` and find the index of the best match from `col1` and grab the associated value with the index?

Comment: that also work, could u please help me how to get the index? I tried to use `array_position` but I couldn't get it

Comment: could you give me the initial dataframe before the `map_from_arrays`?

Comment: I just edited the question dear. Thank you so much, I have spent a lt on this part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe like this.

```py
data = [
[["come and get", "computer", "come and get more" ], "come for good", ["this is one","useful device" , "sure things"]],
[["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"], "hot tea", ["about season" ,"oh yea", "tempters"]],
[["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"], "hot summer", ["about season","oh yea","tempters"]]
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

First, I use your method to get the number of intersections. Then, use `array_max` and `array_position` to get the index where it has the most intersections.

*The Spark SQL's `array_position` only accepts static value for the 2nd argument, so I had to use the SQL expressions.

```py
c1_arr = F.col('col1')
c2_arr = F.split(F.trim('col2'), '\s+')
df = (df.withColumn('cnt', F.transform(c1_arr, lambda x: F.size(F.array_intersect(c2_arr, F.split(F.trim(x), '\s+')))).alias('cnt'))
        .withColumn('best_match', F.expr('array_position(cnt, array_max(cnt))'))
        .select('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 
          F.col('col1').getItem(F.col('best_match') - 1).alias('match'),
          F.col('col3').getItem(F.col('best_match') - 1).alias('match_value'))
)
```

- Note that `array_position` is 1-indexed, so I need to -1 when I use in `getItem`.
- Also, the tie breaker is not specified in this question and all of rows have ties in this example, so the result could be different from what you have. (I believe `array_position` will return the first matching value.)